# Best Practises of React using external Axios and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I was looking for good answers in 2023.
How to handle in the best way React + external Axios + useEffect?

Let me show you mein code:

```
export const getTransactions = async () => {
  try {
    const response: any = await axios.get('transactions');
    return response.data.transactions;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Get Transactions Error', e);
  }
};
```

- using it

```
useEffect(() => {
    const data = getTransactions();
    console.log('INSIDE DATA', data);
    setTransactions(data);
  }, []);
```

I want get data once => but I'm receiving Promise. Do I really need to do .then on getTransactions() or maybe there today is more smart way to return just data not Promise hmm?

Thanks Team!

Answer (score 0):

`getTransactions` is returning a promise, so you need to await the results. But you can't have an async callback in useEffect, so you can do this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchTransactions = async () => {
    const data = await getTransactions();    // <- await this result
    console.log('INSIDE DATA', data);
    setTransactions(data);
  }
    
  fetchTransactions();
    
}, []);
```

or

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getTransactions().then(data => {
    console.log('INSIDE DATA', data);
    setTransactions(data);
     
   });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Can we do it in a different way? Just to return asynchronously data returning just value without Promise?
Grazie!

Comment: no, async functions always return a promise. since you need the resolved promise to be able to set your state you need to wait for it to be resolved with `await` or `then()`. if you don't want to wait for the promise to be resolved you'll have to refactor your code so that your data isn't coming from an async function